# Hive Query - Get max and sum of multiple fields from each group

Tags: sql, hadoop, hiveql

I have a table as follows:

```
id | most_recent_run  | flag1 | flag2
---+------------------+-------+------
1  | 2017-01-01 10:40 | 0     | 1
1  | 2017-01-01 18:30 | 1     | 1 
2  | 2017-02-28 04:30 | 1     | 0
```

I want to query this table such that for every `id`, I get the `max(most_recent_run)`, `sum(flag1)` and `sum(flag2)`. This should be the query result:

```
id | max_most_recent_run | flag1_count | flag2_count
---+---------------------+-------------+------------
1  | 2017-01-01 18:30    | 1           | 2
2  | 2017-02-28 04:30    | 1           | 0
```

I have tried writing this query using a combination of collect and rank functions but I am not getting the intended results.

Any explanation or direction in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the SQL [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement, then use the `max` and `sum` functions, *i.e.*:

```
select id,
    max(most_recent_run) as max_most_recent_run,
    sum(flag1) as flag1_count,
    sum(flag2) as flag2_count
from my_table
group by id
```